# Iterating over a ndarray by taking current and next row

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have an ndarray of columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100],
[111,222,333,444,55,666,777,888,999,1000],
...............................,
.............................]
```

I want to take one row and next row iteratively and compute some operations with same column values for the two consecutive rows.
Example,
I have to take ith row and i+1th row
then iterate over each of the values for these rows say (1-11) and (2-22).......... in one step
in next step I have to take next two rows such as (11-111) and (22-222)............... as next step.
The end goal is to have one matrix that has all these values.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say that we have:

```
test = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100],[111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000],[1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,10000]]
```

`test` can also be a `np.ndarray`. Then you can perform what you want to do like this:

```
for i in range(len(test) - 1):
    print(f"Iteration number {i}")
    for (value1, value2) in zip(test[i], test[i + 1]):
        print(value1, value2)
```

This results in:

```
Iteration number 0
         1 11
         2 22
         3 33
         4 44
         5 55
         6 66
         7 77
         8 88
         9 99
         10 100
Iteration number 1
         11 111
         22 222
         33 333
         44 444
         55 555
         66 666
         77 777
         88 888
         99 999
         100 1000
Iteration number 2
         111 1111
         222 2222
         333 3333
         444 4444
         555 5555
         666 6666
         777 7777
         888 8888
         999 9999
         1000 10000
```

Comment: For iterating over first with second, then first with third,........, then second with thrid, second with fourth......... what can we do?

Comment: ```test = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100],[111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000],[1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,10000]]
for i in range(len(test) - 1):print(f"Iteration number {i}")
    for j in range(i+1, len(test)-1):
        for (value1, value2) in zip(test[i], test[j]):
            print(value1, value2)```

Comment: What are "first"/"second" in your example? First row? Column? Please add a small example to show what you're trying to achieve with the expected result

Comment: first iteration first row and second row elementwise operation 1=> 11,2=>22,........ in second iteration first row and third rows likewise, the code I have mentioned works for this